# Show that any subset $E$ of the infinite binary sequences $2^N$ with |E| > 1 is disconnected.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If $X = 2^\mathbb{N}$ is a metric space with the metric $d((a_i),(b_i)) = \sum\limits_{i \geq 1} \frac{|a_i - b_i|}{2^i}$, I'm supposed to show that any $E \subseteq X$ that's not empty or a singleton is disconnected.

A hint came attached suggesting that I consider two points in $E$ and assume their first entries are different, then consider neighborhoods around those points, but I'm not exactly sure where that leads me. I feel like it leads to an explicit union of two neighborhoods which equals $E$, but I just don't see how.

Any hints, tips, or suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each index $i$, $X$ is the union of the disjoint open sets $X_{i,0}=\{x\in X:x(i)=0\}$ and $X_{i,1}=\{x\in X:x(i)=1\}$.

Suppose that $E\subset X$ contains two distinct elements $x$ and $y$. Then there is some index $i$ where $x(i)\neq y(i)$. Therefore the sets $E\cap X_{i,0}$ and $E\cap X_{i,1}$ are both non-empty and their union is $E$, so $E$ is not connected.

Comment: Oh man, I feel like an idiot. I was trying to use the metric to define my two disjoint open sets and couldn't figure out how to do it. This is nice and simple!